# ListView и post-запрос

Tags: django

Подскажите, как лучше обрабатывать post-запрос в ListView, у него ведь нет метода form_valid?
Нужно переопределять функцию post? Тогда можно ли так?

```
def post(self, request):
    form = ChoiceThema(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['choice'] == 1:
            self.queryset = self.Thema.objects.all().order_by('created')
        if form.cleaned_data['choice'] == 2:
            self.queryset = self.Thema.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    return redirect("forum")
```

Comment: можно, работать будет (если правильно напишите)

Comment: Ну можешь попробовать или как-то сделать это в методе get_context_data

Comment: посмотрите как работает Create/UpdateView и сделайте по аналогии